# which one is faster/smarter and why: COUNT(*) or storing the numbers each the do something

Tags: php, mysql, performance

PHP

```
$total_points = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as Num FROM account WHERE id='$id'"),0)
```

Mysql account table

```
|user_id|
```

mysql points table

```
|id | user_id | points |
```

or

PHP

```
$total_points = mysql_query("SELECT points FROM account WHERE id='$id'");
```

Mysql account table

```
|user_id| points |
```

Mysql points table

```
|id | user_id | points |
```

Comment: because you are only going to get 0 or 1 results a much better optimization would be to add indexing and/or unique... ALTER TABLE `points` ADD UNIQUE (
`id`
)`

Comment: no, the query will return users current point on the site. take stack overflow for example they show us how much points we have, like me i just have 20 points - which mean i have done something, and that something being recorded in a table and points for each something given. the total point counted by summing up all the individual something points. so my question is should i use COUNT(user_id) method or storing variable method?

Answer (score 3):

Storing the variable would probably be faster, but that also means constantly updating it, which can be less efficient / slower in the long run.

Using `COUNT(id)` will be much better than `COUNT(*)`, however. So my vote would be to use `COUNT(id)` :)

Comment: im working on a players points system, where a user earns points through playing games, the points will be recorded on the points table. and im thinking of showing the users point next to their user name throughout the whole site/or at least at his/her profile page.

I dont get it, why you're saying it will be slower/less efficient in long run? you think what method does popular portals such as NewGround/Kongregate uses to show the users points? 

do they use the storing as variable method, or the dynamic COUND(id)? if COUND(id) they should be facing alots of performance issues, dont they?

Comment: `COUNT(id)` is not faster than `COUNT(*)`. Unless you're using some sort of aggregation, those two are semantically synonymous.

Answer (score 0):

First off, for the first line you had, I believe it's faster to use `FOUND_ROWS()` than `COUNT(*)`.

```
$total_points = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() FROM account WHERE id='$id'"),0)
```

The second approach would be faster once that points table grows large, but you need to make sure you increment the account table properly so those values are in sync. It could become inaccurate if you forget to add the points in some places, or forget to delete them, etc.

Comment: exactly, when the points table grow large FOUND_ROWS method will be slower. So is it preferred to do FOUND_ROWS every time when getting the total points earned by user? or calculate them and save it to the accounts table with additional 'points' column and load the points from there? and also create a php in the admin panel to update the accounts 'points' column often? which would be the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

The `COUNT(*)` or query version should be faster because you are not going futher down to `mysql_num_rows`. For counting you don't need all fields (`*`), you should simply do `COUNT(fieldID)` which is a lot faster.

**Few Points To Note:**

Note that you are getting only one row anyways because you are using `where` clause, in other words, the result will be either one row or no row if not found:

```
$total_points = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as Num FROM account WHERE id='$id'"),0)
```

Normally you should count when you are expecting more than one record eg:

```
$total_points = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as Num FROM account"),0)
```

Again, for optimized query, use a single field:

```
$total_points = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(fieldID) as Num FROM account"),0)
```

Comment: So which one would be the best choice? storing variable in users account table or dynamically fetching the points via COUND(id)?